# Why does this C++ code crash?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to run this code in Windows 7, after it has compiled successfully. Any ideas on why it crashes? I've given it a random generated binary file as an input to test, but as soon as it begins, the application crashes.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>
using namespace std;

long getFileSize(FILE *file) {
        long currentPosition, endPosition;
        currentPosition = ftell(file);
        fseek(file, 0, 2);
        endPosition = ftell(file);
        fseek(file, currentPosition, 0);
        return endPosition;
}

struct frame {
        uint8_t bytes[535];
};

struct spectralFrame {
        uint8_t bytes[512];
};

struct spectralFrameWord {
        uint16_t words[256];
};

int main() {
        char *filePath = "C:\\Payload\\Untitled.bin";
        uint8_t *fileBuffer;
        FILE *file = NULL;
        file = fopen(filePath, "rb");
/*      if((file = fopen(filePath, "rb")) == NULL)
                cout << "Failure." << endl;
        else
                cout << "Success." << endl;
*/
        long fileSize = getFileSize(file);
        fileBuffer = new uint8_t[fileSize];
        fread(fileBuffer, fileSize, 1, file);
        fclose (file);
        long frameCount = fileSize / 535;
        frame *frames = new frame[frameCount];
        for(int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0; i < fileSize; i++) {
                frames[j].bytes[k++] = fileBuffer[i];
                if((i % 534) == 0) {
                        j++;
                        k = 0;
                }
        }
        delete fileBuffer;
        fileBuffer = NULL;
        spectralFrame *spectralFrames = new spectralFrame[frameCount];
        for(int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
                for(int j = 22, k = 0; j < 534; j++) {
                        spectralFrames[i].bytes[k++] = frames[i].bytes[j];
                }
        }
        delete frames;
        frames = NULL;
        spectralFrameWord *spectralFrameWords = new spectralFrameWord[frameCount];
        uint16_t word;
        for(int i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
                for(int j = 0, k = 0; i < 511;) {
                        word = spectralFrames[i].bytes[j++] << 8;
                        spectralFrameWords[i].words[k++] = word | spectralFrames[i].bytes[j++];
                }
        }
        delete spectralFrames;
        spectralFrames = NULL;
        filePath = "C:\\Payload\\Untitled.tsv";
        file = fopen(filePath, "w");
/*      if((file = fopen(filePath, "w")) == NULL)
                cout << "Failure." << endl;
        else
                cout << "Success." << endl;
*/
        for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
                fprintf (file, "%u\t%u\n", i, spectralFrameWords[0].words[i]);
        }
        fclose (file);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't link to external pages, include the code in the question.

Comment: Why are you using `stdio` instead of `iosream`?

Comment: **Never** store a string literal in a non-const `char *`. I would suggest using actual C++ features, like `std::string` and `std::vector`.

Comment: C with `new`, haven't seen C++ used in that particular way before...

Comment: I'm really new to writing code. I have no idea to use the debugger. I'm sorry! I'm using `cstdio` because I wanted to leverage the `fread()` function, which according to an article I was reading was recommended for the task.

Comment: Can you use MS Developer Studio? If yes, it will show you at which line in your code the crash happened. Then update your question with this valuable info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `new[]` you need to use `delete[]`, not `delete`.  I see three violations of this rule in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a c code not c++. Except the new [] delete [] try to run this with a valgrind it will most probably show you all the bad stuff you have in.